# Let $f : [0;1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f : [0;1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$. Which of the following statements are true?
a. If $\int_ 0^{\pi} f(t) \cos nt\, dt = 0,$ for all $n \in {0} \cup \mathbb{N}$, then $f= 0$.
b. If $\int_ 0^{\pi} f(t) \sin nt\, dt = 0,$ for all $n \in  \mathbb{N}$, then $f= 0$.
c. If $\int_ 0^{\pi} f(t)\,t^n\, dt = 0,$ for all $n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$, then $f= 0$.

---

My thoughts:-
(a) it is not true as we can take $f(t)=\sin{nt}$.
(b)no idea.
(c)it is true.

Does my answers correct?
and what about (b)

Comment: You can't take $f(t)=\sin nt$ since $f$ is fixed and $n$ is varying (notice th *for all* $n$).

Comment: Why do you think (c) is true? Please explain.

Comment: What is $\int_{0}^\pi f(t) cos(nt)dt$ for $f$ defined on $[0,1]$? There must be an error in the formulation...

Answer (score 1):

All the three are correct.

c. is true due to [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

For a. extend $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ as an even function. Then, if a. holds for $\cos nx$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, by symmetry, and for $\sin nx$ since $f$ is even.

For b. extend $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ as an odd function.

For a. and b. we use the fact that: If $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and
$$
\int_{\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\cos nx\,dx=\int_{\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\sin nx\,dx=0, \quad\text{for every}\,\,
n\in\mathbb N,
$$ 
then $f$ is constant.

Comment: are you sure?because in the answer it is given that all three are correct.I feel that you are correct though.

Comment: @user118413: Yes I am sure. Try the counterexamples I have suggested!

Comment: This answer is false: $\int_0^\pi sin(t)cos(2t)dt=-\frac23$, so it is nonzero!

Comment: Actually I am wrong. I thought the integral was from $0$ to $2\pi$. I am now editing the answer.

Comment: See updated version.

Comment: $$\hat f (n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$$ This will come when u use even function AND Parseval's identity..But how this equality comes?

Answer (score 1):

[Parseval's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) shows that a) and b) are true: For a) extend $f$ as an even function; For b), extend $f$ as an odd function.

c) is correct

we don not need $f(0)=0$

there exist $M\gt0$ such that $|f(x)|\lt M$

By Stone-Weierstrass Theorem,  $\forall  \epsilon \gt0$, there exist a polynomial $P(x)$ such that

$$\int_0^\pi|f(x)-P(x)| dx\lt  \epsilon.$$

Since $\int_ 0^{\pi} f(t)\,t^n\, dt = 0 $, we have $\int_0^\pi f(x)P(x) dx=0$, so

$$\int_0^\pi f^2(x) dx = \int_0^\pi f^2(x) dx - \int_0^\pi f(x)P(x) dx = \\
\int_0^\pi f(x) (f(x) -  P(x) )dx\leq \int_0^\pi |f(x) (f(x) -  P(x) )|dx \\
\leq M \int_0^\pi |f(x) -  P(x) |dx \lt M\epsilon$$

Hence, 
$$\int_0^\pi f^2(x) dx  =0$$

so $f\equiv 0$

Comment: Could you please describe more about option (a) and (b)? Nice proof for option (c)!:)